# How can I enable VNC server over ssh after machine just booted?

Tags: vnc, remote-desktop, solus

Suppose I remotely start my Solus linux machine with Wake-On-Lan. Then I would like to connect to it using VNC, but seems like VNC server is not running yet.

After machine just booted, there is no user currently logged in and on the screen it asks you to choose user and type your password. After which it starts my desktop environment and VNC becomes available. The problem is that I do not know the way to log in to desktop environment remotely while connected over ssh. Is there such way?